# allow html tags with mongoid + ruby on rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, wysiwyg

I have this object y my database:

```
 => #<Page _id: 50683d421d41c8363d000060, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-09-30 12:38:26 UTC, title: "Terms", description: "Terms of use... <b>description</b>", published: true, slug: "terms">
```

On description field I have added with https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails  a **b** tag for bold.

But When I render my page I can see:

```
Terms of use... <b>description</b>
```

**How can I render html tags on my mongodb database data?**

#### Preview

http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1766-71.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails escapes html by default for security's sake.

When you trust content, tell Rails:

```
<%= raw your_variable %>
```

Or:

```
<%= your_variable.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not a rails variable is a plain text from admin interface wiht wysiwyg editor. I have added a image.

Comment: it doesn't change anything :) use `raw`